# Linux Mint 21.1 gets black screen after grub menu on install

Tags: linux

I have a desktop computer which was alreary running Linux Mint 20. Now I'm trying to install Linux Mint 21.1, from scratch (I want to do a new install). I burned the iso on a new usb drive using the mint image burner tool.
I go into the boot menu, pick my USB drive, and then I get a menu asking if I want compatibility mode, etc. No matter what I select, it then sends me to a black screen with just a cursor, and it just stays like that indefinitely (I waited pretty long).

I read elsewhere that it might be a compatibility problem with the drivers. I'd be surprised that there would be such a big difference between version 20 and 21 but I tried this anyways : https://www.linux.org/threads/linux-mint-wont-install-black-screen.13482/ Now on the black screen I have a message saying "Booting a command list" and the same blinking underscore, and still nothing happening.

I don't know what is wrong since the last version of Mint was working fine, I would think it's not a compatibility problem, but I don't know what it is, and it seems different from most of the other questions on the subject I have found.

Comment: Your link mentions Nvidia graphics. If that's your case then you definitely should try the suggestions there.

Answer (score 2):

It eventually worked! apparently, it was just taking an abnormally long time loading. After trying a few things that did not work, I decided to wait on the cursor screen for more than 30 minutes and it ended up booting into Linux Mint normally and I was able to install it